# Loaded the nib file but the view outlet was not set

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I deleted the universityPicker.xib accidentally and then made a new one with the same name but no connection could be done. The file crashes and gives this message

```
reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "universityPicker" nib but the view outlet was not set."
```

How I can fix it?

Comment: What do u mean no connection can be done ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Open the universityPicker.XIB file

  - Click on file's owner icon on the left bar
  - Click on the third tab in the right-hand sidebar
  - Under "Custom Class" at the top, make sure Class is the name of the ViewController that should correspond to this view. If not, enter it
  - In the right-hand sidebar, click on the last tab
  - You should see "outlets" with "view" under it. Drag the circle next to it over to the "view" icon on the left bar
  - Save the xib and re-run

Comment: EXTREMELY HELPFUL!! :-)

I was testing the possibility of putting all my views into a Presentation folder. I received this error and knew that all my subviews were hooked up. The last 3 bullet of your answer was to magic trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Interface Builder you should connect the View to the File's Owner.

Comment: i can't connect files owner to view or any object and visa versa

Comment: Then set first the File's Owner's class ( 3rd tab on the Utilities pane on the right ) to your viewController's name.